# getting {"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"} when querying couchbase via http

Tags: couchbase

I have couchbase `2.5.1-1083-rel-enterprise` on my mac, and `3.0.1-1444-rel-community` on my windows machine.

- When I create a test document in the default bucket using the admin UI in  `(2.5)` and access it via http,  e.g. `http://localhost:8092/default/001` I see the document.
- When I create any test document using the admin gui in `(3.0)` on windows and make the same http request, I get `{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}`, even though the document is visible in "Documents" and I can edit the document via the admin gui?

Has anyone else experienced anything similar in ver 3.0 ? It's almost as if in version 3.0 you can no longer query a document via http using  `{server}/{bucket}/{id}` url syntax?

I've tried creating buckets with and without passwords in 3.0 and this doesn't appear to make any difference. Also, I can access the documents in 2.5 as well as 3.0 using the GUI as well as with a client library, so it's not a case of the document not existing in the bucket.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In couchbase, port 8092 is the one dedicated to views REST API.

Prior to 3.0 (which is the case on your Mac box), it was an undocumented feature that the view REST API would allow you to `get` a document, for debugging purpose. Starting with 3.0 this path isn't available anymore. The documentation of the [REST API for 2.5](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-rest-api/) begins by stating that

> The REST API should not be used to read or write data to the server. Data operations, such as set and get for example, are handled by Couchbase SDKs. See the Couchbase SDKs.

Please use the SDKs, or use the view REST API as [intended](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/REST/rest-views-intro.html) (for querying views)

Comment: the simplistic 'missing' error message is confusing though (refers to a missing view or design document)

Comment: If you want a simple cli tool to read doc, I recommend `cbc cat` which is part of libcouchbase2-bin.

Comment: txs for the clarification, appreciated, A